# retrive only mobile-supported video from YouTube API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API to retrieve videos for and Android client.

The program works well but sometimes I get an error like "this video is not allowed to run on smartphones".

So, there is a way to filter that videos? I read [this doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#categorysp) but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two concepts embeddable and syndicated.
iOS devices use iframe so they basically embed. 
Android devices that use player API can check syndicated.

When you do a [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), you can set [videoEmbeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoEmbeddable) and [videoSyndicated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated) to true.

For Android, you should check [videoSyndicated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoSyndicated).

Or if you are iterating through videos, for each video, you can do a [video->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) call with video id and check [status.embeddable](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.embeddable) in the response.

Here is a [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html) about this topic, even though examples are in v2, information is still relevant.

Comment: Thanks for reply! So the domain https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos is deprecated?
I tried to use "videoSyndicated=true&v=3" with this API but does not work. I will update my program to v3 using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/

Comment: videoSyndicated is an option in v3, there should be a way to do it in v2 as well. But switching to v3 is highly recommended.

Comment: I tried this with v3 API and the video returned from the query still does not play on my Galaxy Tab using YouTube Player APIs. It just displays "This video is unavailable on this platform". Are you sure this works? Here is the query I used 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?maxResults=5&part=snippet&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&q=Tango+Kenny+G&key={YOUR_API_KEY}'. And the first videoId returned was 'gEazvWRo7h0' which does not play on my device.

Comment: YouTube app has no problem filtering out the videos that cannot be played on mobile. This should be the case with API search results.

Comment: I've had a video such as Twister, Episode 1 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSdbE5uxINs) returned from a query set up like this.  The video is playable in the YouTube mobile app, but not on mobile using the embedded iFrame player.  Something is wrong with YouTube's backend, the query is not working as intended.

Comment: Setting videoEmbeddable and videoSyndicated to true does not seem to work: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={api_key}&part=snippet&type=video&q=Twenty+One+Pilots+Stressed+Out&videoCategoryId=10&maxResults=3&regionCode=GB&videoSyndicated=true&videoEmbeddable=true returns video id pXRviuL6vMY as first result, and if Android sdk is used to play it, it shows the restricted content error.