# how to ensure that a youtube API response only contains videos that are suitable for playback on a mobile device

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to add some youtube videos from my Admin page to database. So that mobile application can make use of them to play.

I want to filter the result from [YouTube API link](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=lumia&key=XXXXXXXXXXX&maxResults=20&pageToken=CCgQAA) so that i can make sure that whatever videos i add to the database will be able to play on mobile devices like IOS and Android.

I tried

> &format=5 and &format=1

but no use.

I also went through [Youtube API v2.0 Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial?csw=1#Retrieving_Videos_for_Mobile_Playback) but unable to find the correct way to assign **fields** parameter to my query string

can anyone guide me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is videoEmbeddable and videoSyndicated.

Here's my answer to original question: [retrive only mobile-supported video from YouTube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003041/retrive-only-mobile-supported-video-from-youtube-api/19008571#19008571)