# How can I limit YouTube videos that fail when playing with the error "This video is unavailable on this platform"?

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am making an Android app that searches and plays YouTube videos on a mobile device. Currently, I am parsing the results given back by this YouTube data request and the user selects one to be played.

YouTube request for "song title":

> `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=Music%2Csong+title&q=song+title&v=2&alt=jsonc&orderby=viewCount&format=1,6&type=video&videoSyndicated=true&prettyprint=true&videoEmbeddable=true&max-results=5`

The problem is that certain videos will not play and will fail with the error "*This video is unavailable on this platform.*" I understand that this is because some videos are not allowed to be played on mobile devices. However I do not see a way of determining if they are playable without actually trying to play them. I have looked high and low for days! `videoSyndicated` does not seem to help.

Does anybody have any good ideas?

Comment: There is a solution for v3 API at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003041/retrive-only-mobile-supported-video-from-youtube-api/19008571#19008571

Comment: Well I tried it but it did not work for me :(  Best approach I found so far is if I attach a PlayerStateChangedListener to the YouTubePlayer instance, onError() is called with 'ErrorReason.NOT_PLAYABLE' when loading the video. I can then try to play a different video.

Comment: YouTube filters search results on their own mobile site & Android app. They only show search results that play. The fact that they apparently created a mobile data api that returns unplayable results seems to be a major oversight or simply deep inconsideration for devs and users alike. This should be fixed immediately and since they seem to have no issue filtering on their own site means the hooks are there.